# Printing receipts via CUPS - Keep orientation

Tags: pdf, printing, cups

I'm building a simple POS system, and have a receipt printer. I've got the system basically completed, but CUPS prints everything portrait. This means that if the receipt is shorter than it is wide, CUPS sends it to the printer sideways, which looks completely wrong (and clips about 60mm off of the left hand side of the receipt).

My system creates a PDF which is then sent to the printer. The PDF is produced correctly, how can I get CUPS to stop rotating the print?

I've seen answers such as making sure the document fits the expected input exactly, but that wouldn't work for a variable length receipt.

I've also tried to set the orientation manually when printing and as default options, but CUPS seems to ignore any rotation instructions.

The printer in question is a Seiko Instruments RP-D10.

printers.conf

```
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
NextPrinterId 2
<Printer RP-D10>
PrinterId 1
UUID urn:uuid:ec55ffd0-01c2-36cf-545c-84174ebae871
Info RP-D10
MakeModel SII RP-D10 (80mm)
DeviceURI usb://SII/RP-D10
State Idle
StateTime 1636338040
ConfigTime 1636338040
Type 53252
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

RP-D10.ppd

```
*FormatVersion:         "4.3"
*FileVersion:           "1.0"
*LanguageVersion:       English
*LanguageEncoding:      ISOLatin1
*PCFileName:            "sii_rpd10_80.ppd"
*Manufacturer:          "SII"
*Product:               "(RP-D10 (80mm))"
*1284DeviceID:          "MFG:SII;CMD:SII;MDL:RP-D10;CLS:PRINTER;"
*cupsVersion:           1.2
*cupsManualCopies:      True
*cupsModelNumber:       4
*cupsFilter:            "application/vnd.cups-raster 0 rastertosii"
*ModelName:             "RP-D10 (80mm)"
*ShortNickName:         "RP-D10 (80mm)"
*NickName:              "SII RP-D10 (80mm)"
*PSVersion:             "(3010.000) 550"
*LanguageLevel:         "3"
*ColorDevice:           False
*DefaultColorSpace:     Gray
*FileSystem:            False
*Throughput:            "1"
*LandscapeOrientation:  Plus90
*VariablePaperSize:     True
*TTRasterizer:          Type42


*% Print Quality
*OpenUI *PrintQuality/Print Quality: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 5 AnySetup *PrintQuality
*DefaultPrintQuality: Normal
*PrintQuality Normal/Normal mode: "<</cupsBitsPerColor 8/HWResolution [203 203]>>setpagedevice"
*PrintQuality Draft/Draft mode: "<</cupsBitsPerColor 8/HWResolution [101 101]>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *PrintQuality


*OpenUI *PageSize/Media Size: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *PageSize
*DefaultPageSize: X72MMY200MM
*PageSize X72MMY200MM/72mm * 200mm: "
      <</PageSize[204 567]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageSize X72MMY1000MM/72mm * 1000mm:   "
      <</PageSize[204 2835]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageSize A4/A4 reduced to 72mm:    "
      <</HWResolution [69 69]/PageSize[595 842]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageSize Letter/Letter reduced to 72mm:    "
      <</HWResolution [67 67]/PageSize[612 792]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageSize SELECTPAPERXXMM/Custom Paper Size(72mm * 297mm):  "
      <</PageSize[204 842]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *PageSize


*OpenUI *PageRegion: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *PageRegion
*DefaultPageRegion: X72MMY200MM
*PageRegion X72MMY200MM/72mm * 200mm:   "
      <</PageSize[204 567]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageRegion X72MMY1000MM/72mm * 1000mm: "
      <</PageSize[204 2835]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageRegion A4/A4 reduced to 72mm:  "
      <</HWResolution [69 69]/PageSize[595 842]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Letter/Letter reduced to 72mm:  "
      <</HWResolution [67 67]/PageSize[612 792]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*PageRegion SELECTPAPERXXMM/Custom Paper Size(72m * 297mm): "
      <</PageSize[204 842]/ImagingBBox null>>
      setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *PageRegion



*DefaultImageableArea:  X72MMY200MM
*ImageableArea X72MMY200MM:         "0.0 0.0 204.0 567.0"
*ImageableArea X72MMY1000MM:        "0.0 0.0 204.0 2835.0"
*ImageableArea A4:                  "0.0 0.0 595.0 842.0"
*ImageableArea Letter:              "0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0"
*ImageableArea SELECTPAPERXXMM: "0.0 0.0 204.0 842.0"


*DefaultPaperDimension: X72MMY200MM
*PaperDimension X72MMY200MM:        "204 567"
*PaperDimension X72MMY1000MM:       "204 2835"
*PaperDimension A4:                 "595 842"
*PaperDimension Letter:             "612 792"
*PaperDimension SELECTPAPERXXMM:    "204 842"


*MaxMediaWidth:  "204"
*MaxMediaHeight: "23219"
*HWMargins:  0 0 0 0
*CustomPageSize True: "pop pop pop <</PageSize[5 -2 roll]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*ParamCustomPageSize Width:        1 points 72 204
*ParamCustomPageSize Height:       2 points 72 23219
*ParamCustomPageSize WidthOffset:  3 points 0 0
*ParamCustomPageSize HeightOffset: 4 points 0 0
*ParamCustomPageSize Orientation:  5 int 0 0

*% Cut Mode
*OpenUI *PageCutMode/Cut Mode: PickOne
*DefaultPageCutMode: FullCutPage
*PageCutMode FullCutPage/Full Cut: ""
*PageCutMode PartialCutPage/Partial Cut: ""
*PageCutMode NoCutPage/No Cut: ""
*CloseUI: *PageCutMode

*% Print Density: PickOne
*OpenUI *PrintDensity/Print Density: PickOne
*DefaultPrintDensity: 100Percent
*PrintDensity 70Percent/70%: ""
*PrintDensity 80Percent/80%: ""
*PrintDensity 90Percent/90%: ""
*PrintDensity 100Percent/100%: ""
*PrintDensity 110Percent/110%: ""
*PrintDensity 120Percent/120%: ""
*PrintDensity 130Percent/130%: ""
*CloseUI: *PrintDensity

*% Cut Timing
*OpenUI *CutTiming/Cut Timing: PickOne
*DefaultCutTiming: Page
*CutTiming Page/Each Page: ""
*CutTiming Document/Each Document: ""
*CloseUI: *CutTiming

*% Blank Image
*OpenUI *BlankImage/Blank Image: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *BlankImage
*DefaultBlankImage: feed
*BlankImage feed/Feed: ""
*BlankImage nonfeed/Non feed: ""
*CloseUI: *BlankImage

*% Dither
*OpenUI *Dither/Dither Type: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *Dither
*DefaultDither: ditherScreen
*Dither ditherNone/None: ""
*Dither ditherScreen/Screen: ""
*Dither ditherErrDiff/Error Diffusion: ""
*CloseUI: *Dither

*% End
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It seems cups sends your job through it's pdftopdf filter. This filter then autorotates the page when it thinks necessary.
I found two ways to resolve this for me:

1. Use the `-o nopdfAutoRotate` print option, or,
2. Replace the `pdftopdf` filter (in `/usr/lib/cups/filter`) by a simple shell script that just passes stdin to stdout:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cat -
```